# How to create a Broadcastreceiver for GoogleCloudMessaging

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I'm very new to Android and trying to get Google Cloud Messaging working in my app. To do this, Google has published lots of usefull documentation for me to start with. I've finished my first steps and my app is able to send his regId (received from the GCM-server) to my own server. 
In Google's documentation I can't find the next step for creating a broadcast receiver. (I think I need this because my app needs to know what to do when a message received.) In the prevous version of the GCM api, google create's a helper-class you can use (use extends to get that working) but for the new GoogleCloudMessaging API I can't find any documentation for receiving an message.

Is there anyone who can tell me how te receive a message from the GCM server in my app?

(I'm sorry for my English)

Comment: have you looked at the documentation? http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html there is also a sample app you can look at too

Comment: This is the sample I've already tried. I get it all working except the "message receive"-part

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyone who can tell me how to receive a message from the GCM server in my app?

If you read the documentation, you seem to have missed [Receive Message](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#app) section, where the sample is given for writing your application and specifies how and where to handle the incoming messages.

Comment: Thank you for the reaction. I've already tried this, but I didn't get the WakefulBroadcastReceiver working. Do you know how to implement this class?

Comment: What problem did you face ?